# Loops and arrays in Java

Tags: java

Here are the directions:

Implement the following method so that it prints all even-valued elements from the even-indexed rows of `arr`, and all odd-valued elements from the odd-indexed rows of `arr`.

Elements of the same row should appear on the same line, separated by a space. Elements of different rows should appear on different lines.

Example:

```
int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 3},
               {1, 2, 3}
               {4, 5, 6}};

printOddEvens(arr);
```

Should print:

```
2

1 3

4 6
```

This is what I have, way off, but in the right direction:

(I know the prints are wrong.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[][] = {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
            }
            if (!i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what code you have written so far. Stack Overflow is not a "please do my homework for me" site, but we're happy to help if you show some effort.

Comment: "Been working on this for an hour" - So I presume you already have *some* code... Can you post it?

Comment: Please show us that you've "been working on this for an hour"

Comment: I think you may find this interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homework

Comment: In an hour, you must have written some code which does something.

Comment: "help save my time" == "Do my homework for me"? Come on, show us what you have done! :)

Comment: What happens when you try to compile it? I guess you get a compiler error maybe?

Comment: this doesnt compile but even if it did it wouldnt be right

Comment: I agree it wouldn't be right. First solve the compilation problems. Look at the compiler error message and fix it. Once you have done it, we can try to continue with the logic of the program. On a first glance I would say there is a problem here: arr[i].charAt(i);

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
public class ArrayFilter {

    private static int[][] arr = new int[][] { {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

    private static void printOddEvens(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
                // rowIndex + value is only even when both are odd or both are even
                // the modulo (%) operator returns the remainder of the division
                if ((row + matrix[row][col]) % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printOddEvens(arr);
    }
}
```

One less future competitor for my job I guess (-;

Comment: Hmmm.. giving him the complete solution doesn't help him really at all :S

Comment: While learning by example isn't all bad, I'm not entirely sure simplying giving the answer or in effect doing user1067478's homework for them is the best way for him/her to learn.

Comment: I understand what is going on here dont worry. I have a problem set of 22 problems like these. I was just having trouble with this one and It was the last one.

Comment: Well at least I had fun!

Comment: +1, Thanks for giving the answer, it's the Stack Overflow way despite those prejudiced against helping newbies.

Answer (score 1):

According to the code you posted, you already know how to loop over an array. Now investigate the array over which you are looping, and see what elements it contains. For example an

```
int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3}
```

obviously contains int's. So when I call `array[0]` I ask the array for its first element, and get an int.

Now investigate your array, see what elements it contains and what might be the problem with the line

```
int num = arr[i].charAt(i);
```

Comment: ok, I fixed that, I think my problem is that I do no know how to go through each of the arrays individually, since it is multi dimensional

Comment: Don't let the multi-dimensional nature of it scare you! An `int[][]` is just an array of `int[]`s. If you had a `String[]`, you'd know how to loop over it and get each `String`, right? (I'm guessing so from the code you pasted above.) It's exactly the same: loop over the `int[][]` and you get an `int[]` in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers here are already addressing the sub-array question, so I'll leave that one be for now. Instead, I'll try to offer some advice on the even/odd checks.

Sometimes it helps to rephrase a question a bit. In this case, I think it'll be helpful if you think not in terms of "print even numbers if the outer loop's index is even, or print odd numbers if it's an odd," but rather, "print if the evenness of the inner number is the same as the evenness of the outer loop's index."

The reason this could be helpful is that it reduces nesting of ifs, which can be confusing to step through mentally. So, where you would have:

```
if outer is even
    if inner is even
        print
else // outer is odd
    if inner is odd
        print
```

You would instead have the simpler:

```
if outer-evenness equals inner-evenness
    print
```

You can see that this has 1/3rd as many ifs, and no nesting. Hopefully that will help you concentrate on the other aspects of the problem.

Comment: Whether the number is even. So, 2 has evenness value of true, 3 has evenness value of false. If it's easier, you can think in terms of `isEven(outerIndex) == isEven(innerNumber)`. Since you're (correctly) using mod to test evenness, basically this means whether `(outerIndex % 2) == (innerNumber % 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Given this is homework, you really need to work this out for yourself, however, here's some pointers for the sort of things you should be doing.

First think about the 2-dimensional array, it's basically a grid, which is perhaps clearer if it's written:

```
int[][] arr = {
  {1, 2, 3},
  {1, 2, 3}
  {4, 5, 6}
};
```

So you need to write a two loops, one the iterates through the rows and one that iterates through the values on each row.  Unlike most grids, in the case of a 2-dimensional array the coordinates are reversed, so to access the third value on the second row, the number 3, (and remembering Java uses a zero based index) you would need to write:

```
arr[1][2]
```

Where 1 refers to the row and 2 to the column.

Given this you should be able to write the loops needed to print out all the values in the array, giving you:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Once you have this the loops are done.

The next bit of the question requires you to determine whether a number is odd or even.  To do this in Java you use the modulo operator `%` so that `i % 2 == 0` implies an even number and `i % 2 != 0` implies an odd number.  I'd pop those operations in two methods `boolean isEven(int i)` and `boolean isOdd(int i)`, then call those methods at the appropriate points within the loops to decide first, whether or not to switch to odd or even number printing mode and second, whether a number is odd or even and should be printed according to that mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to carefully think about the problem at hand. First of all, You have to get access to elements on each sub-array, which is not possible without visiting each of the sub-array. Right? Now, for each sub-array, you have to check its index is even or odd. If it is even you have to print even elements and if it is odd, you have to print odd elements. To access each element and check it, you have to go through the entire sub-array.

I think that now the problem is easily solvable, or at least you got an idea about how much loops you have to use, and what you have to do with each of them. Hope this helps :)

Comment: **even-valued** elements from the even-indexed rows and **odd-valued** elements from the odd-indexed. First dimension decision is based on index and second is based on actual value.

Comment: @viktor Thanks for pointing out that. Edited the answer. +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

For go through each array individually, since is bidimensional you need two loops. For instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = {{1,2,3}, {2,5}};

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
            System.out.println(a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints out

```
1
2
3
2
5
```